# Check conditions across multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python

I have three columns, A,B and C, I want to generate a columns D that contains first three columns' name if any of them satisfy a certain condition. For example, the conditions are: A=0, B>30, C='Pass'. If a row satisfies all three conditions, the D return 'A,B,C'. If a row only satisfies first two, then D returns 'A,B'.

I am trying to use the following code but it only checks a consistent condition 'eq(1)'. Of course I can generate another three columns that return 1 if above condition is met and then use the following code but it's somehow troublesome.

```
df['D']=df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda row: ';'.join(row.index[row.eq(1)]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use apply

```
df['D'] = (df['A'] == 0) & (df['B'] > 30) & (df['C'] == 'Pass')
```

Basically pandas is smart enough to treat all of the conditionals as row by operations, and the & is a boolean operator that combines your conditionals.

Comment: Thanks! However, D should return the column name not a boolean. For example, if A and B satisfy conditions while C does not. Then D return "A,B". I am not checking if three conditions are all met.